# matching a list of files with GNU make

Tags: make

This is the first time that I use GNU make to try to do something a bit less basic. I'd like the default target of a Makefile to look for any one of a number of matching filenames, a naming scheme for what I consider to be root tex files, expressed like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# this is just a sketch, I know this is inaccurate
# and simplified by make's standard...

# mainfiles := main letter report course
mainfiles=(main letter report course)

_readable(){
  if ([ -f "$1" ] && [ -r "$1" ]); then
    return 0
  fi
  return 1
}

# how to make all of these existing targets using GNU make?
# all: $(patsubst %, %.tex, $$(mainfiles))
all() {
  for base in $mainfiles[@]; do
    if _readable "${base}.tex"; then
      latexmk -pdfxe "${base}.tex"
    fi
  done
}

# clean:
#   latexmk -c
clean(){
  latexmk -c
}
```

I'm unsure how to turn this into a makefile.

**edit:**

@G-Man pointed out that my question was unclear at best. Indeed I was in a hurry, and I don't exactly know what I want. I guess want to be lazy, and use `:make` instead of the fancy autocompile plugins from vim.

The point is that I used to edit a `JOBNAME` variable in a generic Makefile that relies on latexmk for all of my (la|xe|lua)tex projects. When I open either of the non-existing files main.tex letter.tex course.tex etc in vim, I have it trigger an autocommand to read in a corresponding skeleton file, copy over my generic Makefile and run `git init` if there's no `.git` folder. Usually I only have one of those `.tex` files in a folder, but there could be more of them.

I want a makefile because of a precompilation step (using [mylatexformat](https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat)), some more granular cleaning commands and something like a `FILTER = 2>&1 | sed -n '/^\(Running\|Package\|Beginning\|Underfull\)/p;/^! /,$$p'` that I can prepend to the compiler commands. The precompilation step, for example, checks `@if ((`grep -c endofdump $(TMP)/$(JOBNAME).tex`== 1 )); then ...`.

My question is to be understood in a lazy attempt to avoid having to specify `JOBNAME`, so that any of the files main.tex letter.tex course.tex etc are treated with the same dependencies, possibly an rsync and a precompilation step that perform checks, and a compilation step that requires `$JOBNAME.pdf` to be made.

I use curly braces in `${mainfiles[@]}` for what I think is good practice. I included the `-f` and `-r` test because I assume that make checks this, too.

Anyway, @meuh's answer was helpful, but I revisited my use of make, in that I think it remains a better choice to just edit `JOBNAME` because of flexibility and future use. I now change it with the power of vim (see [my vim repo on github](https://github.com/sharethewisdom/vim/blob/f7248684b973acc66d3badf7e90f4a119bf37905/autoload/init.vim#L286))

Comment: So basically you want to have a `make` rule which applies to all existing files out of a list of file names, correct?

Comment: That is `bash`, not `make`. Can you explain what you want to do? Just creating something form TeX files should be straight forward.

Comment: (1) Are you trying to generate `main.pdf`, `letter.pdf`, `report.pdf`, and `course.pdf` from the corresponding `.tex` files?  Are you talking about using `make` because you don’t want to run `latexmk` over and over again on a ``.tex`` file that hasn’t changed?  What do you want to do about files that don’t exist?  We can’t read your mind, and people who are highly knowledgeable about `make` might know little or nothing about `latexmk`.  Please *explain* (in English sentences) what you are trying to accomplish *in your question.*  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.)   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) I understand that you are, essentially, using the above bash script as pseudo-code to describe the functionality that you want. But, for future reference,  (2a) you can say `if [ -f "$1" ] && [ -r "$1" ]` (you don’t need the parentheses),  (2b) `if [ -r "$1" ]` is probably good enough (unless you’re concerned that you might someday have a directory or a dangling symbolic link called `main.tex`),  (2c) you can say `"$base.tex"` (you don’t need the curly braces ***here***), and  (2d) you need curly braces in `${mainfiles[@]}`.

Comment: BTW, that function can be hugely simplified: `_readable() { [ -f "$1" ] && [ -r "$1" ] }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a particularly good use of make, as there are no dependencies, but perhaps you are going to add them later, so here is a possible start:

```
MAINFILES = main letter report course
T = $(addsuffix .tex,$(MAINFILES))

default: ${T}
${T}:
        @if [ -f "$@" -a -r "$@" ]; then latexmk -pdfxe "$@"; else :;fi
clean:
        latexmk -c
.PHONY: ${T} clean
```

The default target is `main.tex` etc. To build that file or the others there are no dependencies, so the one-line shell script is run to do the test for file existence and readability, then the wanted command is run. The `else` part is so that make does not stop with an error if the file does not exist.

There is a complication needing a `.PHONY` target, otherwise when the files exist make will see there is no dependency and will do nothing.
This applies to the clean target too, in case you have a file called `clean` in the directory.

Comment: Won't that re-make every target, even if it's already up to date?

Comment: @TobySpeight I agree, but that seems to be what the OP wants, and is what the script version does. As I said, there are no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a simple Makefile that knows how to make PDF from TeX:

```
all: $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf,$(wildcard *.tex))

%.pdf: %.tex
        latexmk -pdfxe $<

.PHONY: all
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to traverse directories and I want only the source files from my list to be compiled, which then creates its .pdf equivalent in the same directory. There could be *.tex files that are meant to be included in the source of the root file, or standalone files that are compiled manually only once.

Comment: That's fairly easy to arrange - just change the `$(wildcard *.tex)` in the `all` rule to match the files you're interested in - probably using `$(shell find ...)`, I expect.